# Scope of a global statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

From [Python Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)

> The global statement has the same scope as a name binding operation in the same block.
>
> If the nearest enclosing scope for a free variable contains a global statement, the free variable is treated as a global.

What do the two sentences mean?

Can you also give examples to explain what they mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

> The global statement has the same scope as a name binding operation in the same block.

This says where the `global` statement applies.

Basically, under normal conditions, when you do:

```
foo = 1
```

inside a function, it makes `foo` a locally scoped variable for that function; even if the name is only assigned at the end of the function, it's local from the beginning, it doesn't switch from global to local at the point of assignment.

Similarly, if your function includes the line:

```
global foo
```

it makes `foo` global for the whole function, even if `global foo` is the last line in the function.

The important part is that it doesn't matter where in the function you do it. Just like:

```
def x():
    print(y)
    y = 1
```

raises an `UnboundLocalError` (because assigning to `y` makes it local for the whole scope of the function, and you print it before giving it a value), doing:

```
y = 0
def x():
    print(y)
    y = 1
    global y
```

will print the global value of `y` (0 on the first call, 1 on the second) on the first line without error (rather than raising `UnboundLocalError` or something else) because `global` statements always apply for the whole function, both before and after where they actually appear, just like local variables are local for the whole scope of the function, even if they're only assigned at the end. Note that modern Python does raise a `SyntaxWarning` for using a global name before the associated `global` statement, so it's best to put `global` statements first for clarity and to avoid warnings.

The part about nested scopes:

> If the nearest enclosing scope for a free variable contains a global statement, the free variable is treated as a global.

covers a really unusual corner case with multiply nested scopes where an outer scope assigns to a local variable, a scope inside that one declares the name `global`, and a scope inside that one uses (but doesn't assign) the name. The short definition is "If you're looking for a variable to read that's not in local scope, as you look through outer scopes for it, if it's a global in one of them, stop checking nested scopes and go straight to global scope". This one is easiest to show by example:

```
foo = 1
def outermost():
    def middle():
        global foo  # Stops scope checking, skips straight to global
        def innermost():
            print(foo)
        return innermost
    foo = 2  # Doesn't change global foo
    return middle
```

With this definition, doing `outermost()()()` will output `1`, because the scope lookup in `innermost` checks `middle`, determines `foo` is global for the `middle` scope, and skips checking `outermost` going straight to the global `foo`.

If instead you had:

```
foo = 1
def outermost():
    def middle():
        # No global declaration
        def innermost():
            print(foo)
        return innermost
    foo = 2  # Doesn't change global foo
    return middle
```

then the output would be `2`; the `foo` lookup in `innermost` wouldn't find it locally, or in `middle`'s scope, but it would find it in `outermost`s scope and pull it from there. It's *extremely* unlikely you'd see a construction like this, but the language docs must be unambiguous when at all possible.